# Selenium IDE Test Runs in GUI - But Fails when run in CL (linkText not Visible)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-side-runner

When my saved project and test runs in the Selenium IDE GUI it's fine, but when I perform the same test called via the command line side runner it fails. The issue appears to be the linkText not being visible, but I don't understand why it would fail when it runs fine form the GUI.

[You can see the last step (8) as passed, with reference to the linkText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ0CK.png)

[I then save the project in my local folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSJOv.png)

[And run it again using the side runner command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzu8Z.png)

ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted: Element Corporate Project/Program/Event (CORP) is not clickable at point (798, 199). Other element would receive the click: ...

It appears that the linkText maybe covered? The weird thing it's visible to me when the selenium test is running, just before it hangs. I did try to add some wait commands, i.e. "wait for element visible". But didn't seem to help.
[Maybe I didn't insert the command properly?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ekx.png)

I feel like I must be missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've found similar threads on GitHub that indicate differences in the way the IDE core and web driver work. One user indicates it actually IDE that's clicking through an overlay. I've managed to overcome my issues using simple pause commands, unsure why the wait commands didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found similar threads on GitHub that indicate differences in the way the IDE core and web driver work. One user indicates it actually IDE that's clicking through an overlay. I've managed to overcome my issues using simple pause commands, unsure why the wait commands didn't work for me.